# Im parsing some text from xml file how can i parse also the names?

Tags: c#

This is the function:

```
private void ParseAndDisplayXml(string filename)
        {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filename);
            var list = document.Root.Elements("Message")
                .Select(
                e => new
                {
                    Date = e.Attribute("Date").Value.ToString(),
                    Time = e.Attribute("Time").Value.ToString(),
                    Text = e.Element("Text").Value.ToString(),
                    Name = e.Element("FriendlyName").Value.ToString()
                }
                );
 string result="";
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
               result += string.Format("Date--{0},Time--{1},Text--{2},Name--{3}", item.Date, item.Time, item.Text, item.Name + Environment.NewLine);

            }
            textBox1.Text = result;
        }
```

Im getting null on the Name variable in this part:

```
                {
                    Date = e.Attribute("Date").Value.ToString(),
                    Time = e.Attribute("Time").Value.ToString(),
                    Text = e.Element("Text").Value.ToString(),
                    Name = e.Element("FriendlyName").Value.ToString()
                }
```

This is some content from the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='MessageLog.xsl'?>
<Log FirstSessionID="1" LastSessionID="2"><Message Date="31/01/2012" Time="10:15:42" DateTime="2012-01-31T08:15:42.467Z" SessionID="1"><From><User FriendlyName="Chocolade"/></From><To><User FriendlyName="adilipman@yahoo.com"/></To><Text Style="font-family:Segoe UI; color:#000000; ">היי</Text></Message><Message Date="31/01/2012" Time="10:15:55" DateTime="2012-01-31T08:15:55.097Z" SessionID="1"><From><User FriendlyName="Chocolade"/></From><To><User FriendlyName="adilipman@yahoo.com"/></To><Text Style="font-family:Segoe UI; color:#000000; ">הייתה לי בעיה עם התוכנת ברקים אבל עכשיו הכל עובד.</Text></Message><Message Date="31/01/2012" Time="10:15:58" DateTime="2012-01-31T08:15:58.897Z" SessionID="1"><From><User FriendlyName="Chocolade"/></From><To><User FriendlyName="adilipman@yahoo.com"/></To><Text Style="font-family:Segoe UI; color:#000000; ">מה השלב הבא ?</Text></Message><Message Date="31/01/2012" Time="10:16:27" DateTime="2012-01-31T08:16:27.775Z" SessionID="1"><From><User FriendlyName="Chocolade"/></From><To><User FriendlyName="adilipman@yahoo.com"/></To><Text Style="font-family:Segoe UI; color:#000000; ">אמרת לי בזמנו לחשב ממוצע של 1000 ערכים ? הכוונה 1000 ערכים בפריים ? כי בפריים יש 256 מספרים לא ?</Text></Message><Message Date="31/01/2012" Time="10:17:03" DateTime="2012-01-31T08:17:03.405Z" SessionID="1"><From><User FriendlyName="adilipman@yahoo.com"/></From><To><User FriendlyName="Chocolade"/></To><Text Style="font-family:Segoe UI; color:#000000; ">לחשב ממוצע של 1000 הערכים הגבוהים ביותר בהיסטוגרמה</Text></Message><Message Date="31/01/2012" Time="10:17:10" DateTime="2012-01-31T08:17:10.405Z" SessionID="1"><From><User FriendlyName="adilipman@yahoo.com"/></From><To><User FriendlyName="Chocolade"/></To><Text Style="font-family:Segoe UI; color:#000000; ">ז"א בפריים</Text></Message><Message Date="31/01/2012" Time="10:17:14" DateTime="2012-01-31T08:17:14.135Z" SessionID="1"><From><User FriendlyName="adilipman@yahoo.com"/></From><To><User FriendlyName="Chocolade"/></To><Text Style="font-family:Segoe UI; color:#000000; ">לא בהיסטוגרמה</Text></Message><Message Date="31/01/2012" Time="10:17:20" DateTime="2012-01-31T08:17:20.142Z" SessionID="1"><From><User FriendlyName="adilipman@yahoo.com"/></From><To><User FriendlyName="Chocolade"/></To><Text Style="font-family:Segoe UI; color:#000000; ">בעזרת ההיסטוגרמה</Text></Message><Message Date="31/01/2012" Time="10:17:50" DateTime="2012-01-31T08:17:50.648Z" SessionID="1"><From><Us
```

What i want to do is that it will show me: adilipman hello
Then: chocolade hi

For now what im getting is a date time and text but i want to add also the name for each line and text so i know who said it.

Comment: I just dont understand why using e.Element for TEXT is working but for FriendlyName its not ?

Comment: Because what you should be looking at is the FriendlyName attribute of the User element. It's right there in the xml! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't FrindlyName an attribute of element user,  which I assume is from the from element and not the to element.

```
e.Element("From").Element("User").Attribute("FriendlyName").Value.ToString()
```